# Issue populating current date into the web form using selenium by reading from excel sheet

Tags: java, selenium

I have the code of getting current date, But i need Set current date -1 i.e yesterday's Date.

However my main issue comes how could I populate in to the webform using selenium , as i do have to read `surname`, `forename`, `DOB` and `medicalreport` (here i need to fill it with yesterday date in `ddMMyyyy` format) reads from Excel File.

Comment: Are you looking for any code to get the yesterday's date or are you looking for to set Yesterday's date in excel?

Comment: looking for the code to get yesterday's date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the is java code to get the Yesterday's Date with format `ddMMyyyy`.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);    
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Hope this help you.Let me know if this work.

Comment: thanks very much Kajal it works, and i more question maybe sounds silly but for novoice its a big deal. my questions is what goes into my webelement sendkeys (?) to read this particular code and populate into my web form please

Comment: Could you please accept my code by clicking accept button on my answer message.

Comment: Hi Kajal , my above question in the comment  of sendkeys stuff has been resolved thanks very much